# Why do my CBV forms have no fields?

Tags: python, django

I've written a CBV using TemplateView to put two forms on a template. However only the submit buttons show up minus the fields.

---

multiple_form.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ context.form1.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ context.form2.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Form1(forms.ModelForm):
    username        = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name1'))
    email           = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address1'))

class Form2(forms.ModelForm):
    username        = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name2'))
    email           = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address2'))
```

---

views.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from article.forms import Form1, Form2

class MultipleFormView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/multiple_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MultipleFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form1'] = Form1
        context['form2'] = Form2
        return context

        success_url = '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try remove redundant 'context' in your html, {{ context.form1 }} would incorrectly links to `context['context']['form1']` which doesn't exist.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the useless `context` in your template, just `form1.as_p` is fine.

   ```
   <form action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form1.as_p }}
       <input type="submit">
   </form>

   <form action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form2.as_p }}
       <input type="submit">
   </form>
   ```
2. You need to **instantiate** a form object and not passing the class in your context. Here, you are passing a class, and Django won't be able to use it.

   ```
   class MultipleFormView(TemplateView):
       template_name = 'blog/multiple_form.html'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(MultipleFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['form1'] = Form1()  # <----
           context['form2'] = Form2()  # note the parenthesis here
           return context

           success_url = '/'
   ```